# Entering text in a class, displaying it in another one

Tags: java, android, class, text, editing

I am trying to make a simple text app in order to learn app dev with Java.

I have 2 classes/activities: DisplayActivity and EditActivity.

**The goal/plan is to have a screen in EditActivity where you can edit a few edittext fields, it saves it and quits the EditActivity when you press ok, you press the button to access DisplayActivity and it shows everything previously entered.**

In the EditActivity, I referenced my textfields and my button, and I convert the input to strings each string variable has its own getter.
From DisplayActivity, I made an EditActivity object that calls the getters on the textview fields, which are also referenced correctly

```java
class EditActivity{
    Button mButton;
    EditText mName;
    DispActivity obj = new DispActivity();

    void onCreate(){
        mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.whatever);
        mName   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.whateveralso);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v){
                  //does the intent thing where it changes the activity to DispActivity
                  String name = mName.getText().toString();
               }
        });
}
```

in DisplayActivity, there is simply the name textview referenced.

I dont have error codes/messages or warnings: everything compiles, builds, and runs nicely, until I run the app... the DisplayActivity works fine, though it displays nothing. But when I try to run the EditActivity, it crashes...

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be with `Intent` and it's result. It's a simple way to share data between activities.

In your `DisplayActivity`, where you start the edit activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(DisplayActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i); //start edit activity
```

In your `EditActivity`, you must set the result before you finish the activity:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",resultString); //put your result string here
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish(); //close edit activity
```

Now in your `DisplayActivity` you get the result by implementing the following method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == 1) {
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
        //display your string here
    }
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        //user canceled the edit activity
    }
   }
 }
```